# How do I highlight a search result in tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

When I search a terminal window in tmux, it sets the cursor the keyword search, but doesn't highlight the matching word. Screen used to do this, and it was much easier to visually find a match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the developer<sup>1</sup>, this isn't currently possible in tmux.

[1] http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27427973

Comment: Good to know. At least I'm not just missing something!

Answer (score 4):

This feature appears to have been added in tmux version 2.4 and later.

Looking through [tmux's release notes](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES):

```
    CHANGES FROM 2.3 TO 2.4, 20 April 2017
     * All occurrences of a search string in copy mode are now highlighted;
       additionally, the number of search results is displayed. The highlighting
       updates interactively with the default emacs key bindings (incremental
       search).
```

I can confirm that highlighting doesn't work in tmux version 2.2, which I was using previously.

Answer (score 2):

I know this article is a little outdated so I thought I might follow up with a possible solution, because I was recently looking for this and think I might have found a solution.

```
set-window-option -g mode-fg colour3
set-window-option -g mode-bg colour0
```

Comment: This sets the search text at the bottom left to "colour3" and "colour0", but doesn't highlight the search results in the window. Is that not what you see?

Comment: Interesting. Those changes worked for me on both Arch and OS X. Just for clarification, this changed the vi mode searching in Tmux in my case. This should not impact Ctrl-F for "Find" within your Terminal Application. Is this what you mean by "search results in the window"?

Comment: That didn't work for me either. It changed the colors of the search prompt, but didn't do anything to highlight the actual match. Tmux 2.1 in OS X, using vi for both mode-keys and status-keys.

Also, I'm a bit surprised to find no documentation of those options in the manfile.

Comment: Same on K-Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (highlight bottom left)